# Virtually is like almost or practically?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms

In the first [definition](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/virtually) of the word *virtually* there is written:

> almost [= practically]:
>
> - Virtually all the children come to school by bus.
> - He was virtually unknown before running for office.

which makes me wonder whether *virtually* means *almost* or *practically*, because the meaning of *almost* is not the same as *practically*, is it?

Could you explain what they mean by this?

If you will take a sentence "You'll be able to understand virtually every aspect of computing", it seems that the word *virtually* has no effect if it means *practically* because understanding is theory, not praxis, and I feel that they don't mean "understand almost every aspect" either.

Does "understand virtually" mean "be able to apply the knowledge in praxis"?

Comment: It's not "understand virtually", it's "virtually every aspect". Which is synonymous to "almost every aspect" or "practically every aspect". *Practically* doesn't have anything to do with praxis vs. theory here, and neither does *virtually* mean "unreal" or "otherwordly". Perhaps you should start by looking up [practically](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practically) and realizing it has more than one meaning.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 You opened my mind. I admit that I changed the question a little with time to have it answered with this `meaning in context` because I didn't want to open another little question. If you will append this to accepted answer its complete answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtually) lists both 'almost' and 'practically' as synonyms for 'virtually'.  The notation Longman uses:

> almost [= practically]:

is (what Longman calls) a [double-click-able cross-reference](http://www.ldoceonline.com/howtouse.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many cases where it wouldn't matter if you'd use the word "virtually" or "practically". However in sentences like -> "My life is virtually a closed cabin" etc, "virtually" would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

From OED:

> **virtual** 4. (adjective) *That is so in essence or effect, although not formally or actually; admitting of being called by the name so far as the effect or result is concerned.*

So in essence, *virtually* means *to all intents and purposes, but strictly speaking not actually*.

Other common alternatives with the same meaning are *effectively*, *in practice*, *almost*, etc.